# How to create login screen UWP, C#, XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I was looking for a solution to my problem in visual studio 2015. I need to create a login page using XAML (Text box for username, password and a button called login for logging in). I have done all of this. Now I need to 'Hard Code' a username and password (something simple such as username: user, password: pa$$word) using C#. I need to validate the username and password (if it is incorrect display an error message) if it is correct it needs to navigate to a different page, we will call this page 'Page2'.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please specify where you have encountered problems, show your code and decide if its [tag:wpf] or [tag:uwp].

Comment: Go through this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prathore/login-and-registration-process-in-wpf-application/ here it was showing login and registration design with functionality in wpf

Comment: There is a document about [Create a Windows Hello login app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport-login), please refer it.

Answer (score 0):

[WPF: Implementing Custom Authentication And Authorization](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25726.wpf-implementing-custom-authentication-and-authorization.aspx)

This will solve all your problems.